# Is it possible to have a vec of a struct with generic phantom data in rust?

Tags: generics, rust, phantom-types

I have some struct:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    // ... non-generic, const fields
    marker: PhantomData<T>    
}
```

Since `PhantomData<T>` is of zero-sized, `Foo<T>` has a compile-time known size. Additionally all `Foo`s are `const`. Thus, the following should be possible:

I want to create a vector (or array) in which I can store `Foo<T>`s of different `T`s. Perhaps something like `Vec<dyn Foo<_>>`. This vector I then want to pass to a function:

```
fn func(foos: &[Foo<_>]) {
    // ...
}

func(&[Foo<i64>::new(), Foo<String>::new()]);
```

This doesn't work, since (according to the compiler) `Foo<A> != Foo<B>`, but actually they are the same in terms of memory layout.

Is there a way to do this/some work-around (perhaps using `unsafe`)?

Using a trait is not what I want since

- using trait bounds removes the possibility of passing different `T`s:

  ```
  fn func<T: SomeTrait>(foos: &[T]);
  ```

  means that I can't pass mixed types, while
- using `dyn SomeTrait` requires Boxing which I want to avoid and which should be unnecessary.

I do realize that this is complicated in that some methods of `Foo<T>` might only be implemented for specific bounds of `T`, but methods which are implemented for all `T`s should still be available.

Comment: `Foo<T>` as defined here definitely implements `Sized`, even if `T` is unsized ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fb2cedc282f2b324bab32c4166819ab3)). Could you post a more complete example of what you're trying to do, and what compiler errors you may be getting?

Comment: @Frxstrem Ouh, sorry. The problem is that I still can't do `vec![Foo<i64>, Foo<String>]`. I updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Why not create a separate struct, `FooShared` that is not generic, and wrap `FooShared` with `Foo<T>` for the generic methods?

Comment: As to your question, this can be done with unsafe code, but I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't think I can do something like `FooShared` since I need to pass `Foo`. Since my project is very hacky already, I am very interested in how to do this with unsafe code

Comment: The methods that are not type-specific would be located on `FooShared`, and `Foo<T>` will contain `FooShared` and have the other methods and wrappers for the type-agnostic methods that call those of `FooShared` (or it will just `Deref` to `FooShared`, if you like hacks).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `Deref` to `FooShared` seems like exactly the type of hack I need. I'm trying my hands on implementing it rn

Comment: You may also want to check [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I just realized that implementing `Deref<Target = FooShared>` still does not allow mixing different `T`s (unless used with `dyn` which would require `Box`ing). Could you please have a look at the updated question?

Comment: Why not just use `FooShared`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you mean `fn func(foos: &[FooShared])`? I want to pass `Foo`. This is for a public api which should be convenient and passing `FooShared` wouldn't be. I have gotten it working using `fn func(foos: &[&(dyn Deref<Target = FooShared>)])` but this is merely acceptable, not the ideal solution

Comment: @Einliterflasche If you can treat a `Foo<i64>` the same as a `Foo<String>` then what is even the purpose of the type parameter? How is `func` supposed to know what each item's `T` is?

Comment: Why won't `FooShared` convenient?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because is would mean boilerplate code (`foo.shared` instead of `foo`)  which I want to avoid.

Comment: @cdhowie the point is that i don't need to know and that there are methods implemented for all `T`s which I would like to access which should be safe to use, right? I could even disregard functions and only access (the non-generic) fields.

Comment: The boilerplate will be there even if you will use unsafe code to convert, so you just need to accept it. You can create a macro to ease it.

Comment: @Einliterflasche Your question talks about storing these values in a `Vec` which would mean the `Vec` owns the values -- how then does the generic argument even come into play if you are trying to erase it? If you want to place references in a container, that makes a bit more sense, and can be done with a trait (without boxing) as `&dyn SomeTrait`.

Comment: You know what, you can even get rid of `Foo<T>` altogether and just use `FooShared`, and have some methods that take a generic parameter.